# Does Haxe support function.apply()?

Tags: haxe

I have a question about Haxe, does Haxe support method.apply(this, paramArray) that is similar to Javascript? Thanks.

Best,
Peter Zhou

Answer (score 0):

Is the method [Reflect.callMethod](https://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#callMethod) or you need something else?

Comment: The source code is from AS3. I want to convert as3 to haxe. AS3 can support method.apply(this, paramArray), or method.call(this, param). I don't know haxe can support such as this way?

Comment: Yes, via above method. https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx/blob/master/test/issues/Issue120.as https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx/blob/master/test/issues/Issue120.hx
Also you could use as3hx library (https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/as3hx) to convert as3 to hhaxe

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just use as3hx library to convert as3 to haxe. However, the main issue I meet is too much compile errors(several hundred)!  I'm deeply disappointed about as3hx result.

Comment: Depends on code, but require some manual fixes. Often errors not so many, I mean after fixing few hundred could disappear

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to ease conversion. However, you can't use thisArg like in AS3 because callMethod ignores first argument (o:Dynamic): pay attention to second trace call.

```
using Main.StaticExtender;

class Main {
    public var value:Int;
    function new() {}
    function foo(x:Int): Int {
        return value = x;
    }
    static public function main() {
    var m = new Main();
    var m2 = new Main();
    trace(m.foo.apply(m,[273998236]));
    trace(m2.foo.apply(m2,[273998237]));
    trace(m.value);
    trace(m2.value);
  }
}

class StaticExtender {
    static public function apply(f:Dynamic,o:Dynamic,a:Array<Dynamic>):Dynamic {
        return Reflect.callMethod(o,f,a);
    }
}
```

Comment: This means haxe method doesn't support apply() and call(). Okay thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, can I use Reflect.callMethod to replace apply method? for instance, Reflect.callMethod(this, supper.create, rest); replaces super.create.apply(this, rest);

Comment: No, you should keep reflection outside (in continuation to previous code)   
m2 = new Main2();
trace(m2.foo.apply(m,[123]));
trace(m2.value);
class Main2 extends Main
{
 public function new() { super(); }
 override function foo(x:Int): Int {
  return super.foo(x);
 }
}
Note how m (object) is ignored by callMethod (picks m2 from m2.foo.apply)